# Boolean search on SQL Server, joining searches question

Tags: sql, sql-server, search, boolean

I am trying to create a user-friendly method of allowing employers to search resumes based on Essential (they must have it) and Desirable (would be nice to have). I was thinking Essential could = AND, Desirable could = OR.

So for example I have come up with the following input fields:

```
Essential = "Sales"
AND
Essential = "Manager"
AND
Essential = "Telesales"
~
Desirable = "Insurance"
OR
Desirable = "Finance"
```

This search would mean the candidate MUST have `"Sales" AND "Manager" AND "Telesales"` and if this in their CV it would also be good if they have `"Insurance" AND/OR "Finance"`

However I've got no idea how to run the query that would first look for the Essentials, and only then the Desirables, then rank accordingly using SQL Server.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

I should also mention that the query will be free-text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run your desirables query on a subquery with all your essentials.

Comment: Thanks for this @jimworm. I found a http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189575.aspx but I wondered if this included the ability to use Free Text searching.

Comment: Oh it's MS-SQL not MySQL. Give it a try I guess?

Comment: I can confirm that you can free text search using Sub-Queries. THanks